# Approach to avoid DOM elements from being removed on .text()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below anchor element which contains a smaller image in it.

```
<a href="#" id="myButton" class="BtnClass">
  <img src="Images/arrow2.png"/>
</a>
```

From Javascript i set the text of "myButton" element using,

```
$("#myButton").text("Submit Form");
```

I understand that `.text()` will set the contents of "myButton" and will remove the existing `img` element.

I want to understand what is the best approach to avoid the `img` element being removed from DOM.

P.S I'm mentioning one simple approach in answer. Please suggest other possible solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add an additional span element like below,

```
<a href="#" id="myButton" class="BtnClass">
  <span id="textHere"></span> <!--New Span-->
  <img alt="IMG NOT AVAIABLE" src="Images/arrow2.png"/>
</a>
```

and set the text on the added span.

```
$("#textHere").text("Submit Form");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that more flexible approach is to use CSS background instead of `img` tag:

```css
#myButton {
    background: url(Images/arrow2.png) no-repeat right center;
}
```

and HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="myButton" class="BtnClass">Submit</a>
```

In this case you don't have to worry about text and can continue using `$("#textHere").text("Submit Form");`.

Check a little demo below.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#myButton').text('Submit Form');
}, 2000);
```

```css
#myButton {
    background: #888 url(https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-20.png) no-repeat right center;
    padding: 5px 20px 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#myButton:hover {
    background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myButton" class="BtnClass">Submit</a>
```

Comment: This changes the existing background style of my button, which is not acceptable.

Comment: You can use `background-image` then. Plus you can use multiple backgrounds so you own styles will not be affected.

Comment: Though this approach looks good, I'll use the approach of my answer which I think is easier for me to do.

Answer (score 0):

try appending the text to the a tag like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myButton").append('Submit Form');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="myButton" class="BtnClass">
  <img src="https://googledrive.com/host/0B3_2aPWXzW1LeDhndmRjRXhWUHc"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to modify first textNode value. In this case you would not need to modify HTML structure of the button.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  
  var button = $('#myButton')[0];
  
  // Create text node if it's not the first child of the button
  if (button.firstChild.nodeType !== 3) {
    button.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(''), button.firstChild);
  }
  
  // Change text node value
  button.firstChild.nodeValue = 'Submit Form';

}, 2000);
```

```css
#myButton {
    background: #888;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    color: #FFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#myButton img {vertical-align: bottom; display: inline;}
#myButton:hover {
    background-color: #AAA;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" id="myButton" class="BtnClass">
  <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/google-material-design-icons/48/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_48px-20.png"/>
</a>
```